# upper triangular matrix with zero entries in diagonal

Tags: r

I tried to create an upper triangular matrix with zero entries in diagonals, but I failed to do so.

Here is my code:

```
w1 <- 0.5
pi <- matrix(w1,5,5)
pi[upper.tri(pi)] <- 0
pi[diag(pi)] <- 0
pi
```

I would like to have my matrix as follows:

```
> pi
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
[2,]  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
[3,]  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0
[4,]  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0
[5,]  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.0
```

However, I got this:

```
> pi
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5
[2,]  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5
[3,]  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5
[4,]  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5
[5,]  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5
```

Where is my mistake?

Then, how can I select or access the non-zero elements from my matrix (upper triangular with zero diagonals) sequentially, that is, element after another ?

Any help please?

Comment: `pi[upper.tri(pi, diag = T)] <- 0` Notice though that you are overriding the constant `pi` which is not good practice.

Comment: for the second part `pi[lower.tri(pi)]`

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer Thank you so much.